# Solr: Multi-word synonyms

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm developing a set of synonyms, where you can find some multi-word expressions, such as:

black berry => blackberry

At the analysis stage, and using the /admin/analysis.jsp tools, I can see that the results are correct.

A query such as "quiero una black berry" returns the following sequence:

The org.apache.solr.analysis.StandardTokenizerFactory {luceneMatchVersion=LUCENE_36}:

```
position    1   2   3   4
term text   quiero  una black   berry
startOffset 0   7   11  17
endOffset   6   10  16  22
type    <ALPHANUM>  <ALPHANUM>  <ALPHANUM>  <ALPHANUM>
```

The org.apache.solr.analysis.SynonymFilterFactory {synonyms=lang/synonyms_es.txt, expand=false, ignoreCase=true, luceneMatchVersion=LUCENE_36}:

```
position    1   2   3
term text   quiero  una blackberry
type    <ALPHANUM>  <ALPHANUM>  SYNONYM
startOffset 0   7   11
endOffset   6   10  22
```

However, if I try this sentence at a "real" query, the request handler (an evolution of the edismax handler), the tokens "black" and "berry" were not replaced by "blackberry".

I've seen [here](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/09a8cc8kz4/multi-word-synonyms-and-analysis-jsp-vs-real-field-analysis-query-index) that you can solve this situation by modifying the FieldQParser plugin.

Anyway, since such post was made almost 3 years ago, I'd like to know if there's some way of solving this problem inside Solr, avoiding having to expand some plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/09a8cc8kz4/multi-word-synonyms-and-analysis-jsp-vs-real-field-analysis-query-index) you should search for "black berry" with quotes as using it without quotes causes an OR query i.e. black OR berry

Answer (score 0):

In Solr-6.5.0 you can enables query-time multi-term synonyms by setting below parameter

*From Documentation*

> #### The sow Parameter
>
> Split on whitespace: if set to false,
>   whitespace-separated term sequences will be provided to text analysis
>   in one shot, enabling proper function of analysis filters that operate
>   over term sequences, e.g. multi-word synonyms and shingles. Defaults
>   to true: text analysis is invoked separately for each individual
>   whitespace-separated term.

[synonym.txt]

```
black berry => blackberry
```

[Example]

```
q=black berry
&sow=false
&debug=query
```

[Debug-Response]

```
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">black berry</str>
<str name="querystring">black berry</str>
<str name="parsedquery">_text_:blackberry</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">_text_:blackberry</str>
<str name="QParser">LuceneQParser</str>
</lst>
```

Now you can see from debug response that I have searched for **black berry**, but synonym filter factory maps to the word that I have mentioned in synonym.txt.