# Multi word synonyms in solr

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm trying to implement multi-word synonyms in solr, specifically of the type

```
msc divina => divina
```

So, if a user enters "msc divina", solr should return results for "divina" only.

The definition in schema.xml looks like this:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" 
    autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
            synonyms="synonyms_de.txt"
            ignoreCase="true"
            expand="false" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_de.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" 
            protected="protwords_de.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_de.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" 
            protected="protwords_de.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It doesn't work.  If I add a synonym filter to the query analyzer, a search on "msc divina" returns every hit for "msc and "divina".

How can I solve this?

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43164795/3593530 stackoverflow answer. This gets fixed in solr-6.5.0

Answer (score 3):

Starting from **Solr 6.4** for multi-word synonyms you need to use `solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory`

> This filter maps single- or multi-token synonyms, producing a fully
>   correct graph output. This filter is a replacement for the Synonym
>   Filter, which produces incorrect graphs for multi-token synonyms.
>
> If you use this filter during indexing, you must follow it with a
>   Flatten Graph Filter to squash tokens on top of one another like the
>   Synonym Filter, because the indexer can’t directly consume a graph. To
>   get fully correct positional queries when your synonym replacements
>   are multiple tokens, you should instead apply synonyms using this
>   filter at query time.

Example of the analyzer for index time:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
</analyzer>
```

Since now token streams are graphs - proper arcs would be provided for multiword synonyms for a file

```
fast → speedy
wi fi → wifi
wi fi network → hotspot
```

[image]

In this case - multiwords would work properly.

Reference to McCandless blog post - http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/04/lucenes-tokenstreams-are-actually.html

Answer (score 1):

From Solr [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory):

> Keep in mind that while the SynonymFilter will happily work with
>   synonyms containing multiple words (ie: "sea biscuit, sea biscit,
>   seabiscuit") The recommended approach for dealing with synonyms like
>   this, is to expand the synonym when indexing. This is because there
>   are two potential issues that can arrise at query time:
>
> The Lucene QueryParser tokenizes on white space before giving any text
>   to the Analyzer, so if a person searches for the words sea biscit the
>   analyzer will be given the words "sea" and "biscit" seperately, and
>   will not know that they match a synonym. Phrase searching (ie: "sea
>   biscit") will cause the QueryParser to pass the entire string to the
>   analyzer, but if the SynonymFilter is configured to expand the
>   synonyms, then when the QueryParser gets the resulting list of tokens
>   back from the Analyzer, it will construct a MultiPhraseQuery that will
>   not have the desired effect. This is because of the limited mechanism
>   available for the Analyzer to indicate that two terms occupy the same
>   position: there is no way to indicate that a "phrase" occupies the
>   same position as a term. For our example the resulting
>   MultiPhraseQuery would be "(sea | sea | seabiscuit) (biscuit |
>   biscit)" which would not match the simple case of "seabiscuit"
>   occuring in a document

In here they describe one problem: you can not search for `sea biscit` and get a match on indexed `seabiscuit`, unless you use `expand=true`, but they also explain what happens at the query time with a multi word query which is your case.

```
msc divina -> msc | divina - phrase query
```

which will match both msc and divina documents. If you can specify at query time that you a searching for `"msc divina"` it will work.

Otherwise you need either a multi-word aware tokenizer at the query time or you can expand the `FieldQParser` plugin to do this for you. You can find more [here](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/09a8cc8kz4/multi-word-synonyms-and-analysis-jsp-vs-real-field-analysis-query-index).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

This is where I get confused: "expand the synonym when indexing", which agrees with what you say above.  But if expand=true (in the index analyzer), do the synonyms expand to "msc", "divina" and "msc divina", because I don't want that.  I want "msc divina" to be a synonym for "divina".

The other confusion is whether I should have a synonym filter on the query analyzer too, and what should the expand value there be?

Comment: It looks like there is a patch submitted for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5379 that deals with the same problem. Check also the related jira issues for additional information. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you will find on internet: https://dzone.com/articles/solution-multi-term-synonyms

Other than that, my solution to this problem was domain specific. In my case, I was certain about my query lengths (i.e. less than 200 or there are only 5-10 words).

1. I have replaced spaces with underscores in synonym entries. Here is one of my synonym entries:

   ```
   "like_to":["love_to","loves_to","need_to","needs_to"]
   ```
2. Use KeywordTokenizerFactory to send full query for filtering

   ```
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   ```
3. Use ShingleFilterFactory to index/query all possible sub-phrases of sizes between `minShingleSize` and `mazShingleSize`.

   ```
   <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true" maxShingleSize="3"/>
   ```
4. Then use PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory to replace whitespaces to underscores (`_`)

   ```
   <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\\s+" replacement="_"/>
   ```
5. Use your synonym filter factory.

#### Example

Query: `I love to travel`

Tokens: `I love, I love to, love to, love to travel, to travel, tavel`

Replaced with `_`: `I_love, I_love_to, love_to, love_to_travel, to_travel, tavel`

Synonym filter turns these into: `I_love, I_love_to, like_to, love_to_travel, to_travel, tavel`

So, it will eventually change the `love to` phrase to `like to`.

Hope this trick helps although it involves costly operations.